# List view with navigation control

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Okay I have fallowed this tutorial to a t.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_-Gpv_-nWU&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_356764#t=54s

And for some reason the project I have created keeps erroring out.

Im not sure as to why. 
when ever I click to run on my iphone sdk
it opens the 
main.m file and highlights this line

"  return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));  "

please someone help I'm not sure as to where else to try thank you

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure in your storyboard that the class names for each view controller are correct.  After you check the names, in your appDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method remove all the code except for return YES.